# How to send QuerySet from HTML template to views via urldispatcher in django

Tags: django, templates, url, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to send QuerySet from index.html to views through urldispatcher. I searched through documentations but mostly have information on int:id, path:kjf, etc. There is some information on keyword args but i don't know much about them. I am beginner to Django and this is my first project, also my deadline for this project is near, so any help will be appreciable.

index.html

listing only necessary code...

```
 {% if datadict and datadict != "Sorry no data found" %}
        {% for item in datadict %}
         <tr>
          <th width="5%" scope="row"><a href="{% url 'index' datadict %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Generate</a></th>
             <td>{{ item.title }}<td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<datadict>', views.index, name='index')
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request, datadict=None):
    if (datadict):
    b = datadict[0] ### this is just testing to see if i am receiving the data in QuerySet from or not
    return render(request, 'dapp/index.html', {'b': b})
```

datadict have this data:-

<QuerySet [{'id': 1002, 'year': '2000', 'sector': 'test', 'topic': 'test1', 'insight': 'dont no', 'url': 'localhost',  'start': '2000', 'impact': 'impaca', 'added': 'January 08 2001', 'published': 'August 03 2001', 'relevance': '4', 'pest': 'test2', 'source': 'CBSE', 'title': 'Adding test data', 'like': '5'}]>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, if I understood your question well, you want to be able to access an URL like this: `/[{'id': 1002, 'year': '2000.../` and then get a page that loads the data in the URL. This is probably not a good idea since QuerySets are not meant to be put in an URL. It is possible, but you would have to convert it to a string, then parse the string, something like this:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:datastr>', views.index, name='index')
]
```

views.py

```
import json

def index(request, datastr=None):
    if (datastr):
        datastr = datastr.replace('\'', '"')  # This is needed because json.loads expects keys and values to be inside double quotes
        datadict = json.loads(datastr)
    return render(request, 'dapp/index.html', {'datadict': datadict})
```

then you can access the page with the url /[{'id': 1002, 'year': '2000'...}]/

This should work, but is really not optimal. If there are quotes in the data, they will be broken, and everything will be strings, even numbers.

Here is something more commonly done: if the data is actually in a database that django can access, it is way better to retrieve it in the view. For example, to get an object by id, you can do this:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>', views.index, name='index')
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request, id=None):
    data = None
    if id:
        # Get data here.
        # For example: data = models.ModelName.objects.get(id=id)

    return render(request, 'dapp/index.html', {'datadict': data})
```

Or, if you actually want the client to **send** data to the server that will be rendered, it's better to use GET parameters or use a POST request.

Comment: What i am trying to do is that first i am getting this 'datadict' or queryset from index view whenever a user select from choices and submit the data through form.

Comment: and was displaying this data in tables which also have a graph generate button with each table row, so when a user click on any of generate button, I need to send this data to the graph view which then will filter this data for graph axis and render the page again so that it can display graph. But problem is whenever a use click on generate button, then it wipes out the data from tables. As a solution i was trying to send whole data to the view which will also render the same data in tables again.

Comment: So i am not able to figure it out if i send only the id of a table row to graph view and not the whole data, then how can i stop graph view render to wipe data in tables.

Comment: Note:- I want to display the graph on same page, with the data selected by user through table row choice.

Comment: Oh so basically you want to keep the data even after a page reload ? Then I think it's better to only send the ID to the server every time, then django will retrieve the data from the database each time. That way, you could use caching to speed up the database query (i can't really help on this one as I never used caching yet).

Comment: now that i think about it using GET parameters shouldn't be too bad either, then in the view you can access them with request.GET.get("parameter")

Comment: As a solution i have rendered the graph view data to another page, so no more graph generating on the same page as tables, which prevents from wiping tables data. I am up-voting your solution because it is somewhat useful in different way.        By the way Thanks!!!

Comment: Edit: Not able to upvote, not enough reputation :)